# C# computer owner name

Tags: c#

I have one problem..
I have image converting program so if one user converting image file then his computer name going into file name.'

Something like this I need:
`John-Doe.23-07-2016.JPG`

But at the moment taking computer name like this: `John-Doe/John-Doe.23-07-2016.JPG`

My code:

```
string user = File.GetAccessControl(textBox1.Text).GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

textBox1.Text is place where program choosing folder where is image files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want the computer name, yet you use username.

You should look into the values in `System.Environment`. There you can get the username using `System.Environment.UserName`, or the computer name using `System.Environment.MachineName`